# adding a custom user folder on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, file-management

Question: How do you add a custom folder to the collection of user folders that come with Ubuntu?

---

Info:

I just loaded my netbook with Ubuntu Desktop 10.04LTS (Desktop because it is an aspire one and the Apocalypse seems to follow when ever i try to install netbook remix onto it). It comes with standard folders like Documents, Music, Pictures, Downloads(though this one doesn't appear until you actually download something), Videos, etc etc. These are handly little folders because they have little symbols on them and are nicely located in my file browser. it is basically like the folder lay out the windows had in vista.

I do a lot of little programing on this computer so i have a folder in which i keep all these single kb code files. Obviously named "Code" that I keep in my home folder. But I would really like to it over listed next to my other user folders.

In summary, how do you add a folder to the listing on the file browser. And, if possible, how do you give it an icon? (I understand fully that I will probably have to make said Icon) those two things are what I'm seeking to do.

~n

P.s. please correct me if I'm using the wrong name. I just guessed and called them "User Folders" because they were folders the user uses. made sense. but if they have another name like "libraries" please say so. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a **Bookmark** either in a nautilus window via `Places`|`Add Bookmark` or in any new-style GTK+ file dialog via the buttons below the path list on the left. The set of existing bookmarks is stored in `~/.gtk-bookmarks`. I don't know that there's a way to assign a custom icon to them though.

Comment: You seem to be right on the icon business. I can assign a custom Icon in the browser, but bookmarks don't adopt them it would seem. I might try some other things, but this was the important thing. Can't believe I didn't even see the book mark menu. I've spent to much time on windows. xD

Answer (score 0):

You can change the folder icon in the properties page of the folder, clicking over the icon. You have some svg icons in /usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/64